# GAE GQL - get entity if list contains item

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I've got an entity with a StringListProperty: 'ids' - a list of ids associated with the entity. I then want to query for that entity by asking if a given id is in ids.

I know you can use filter

```
q.filter("last_name IN", list)
```

but I need the reverse, something like:

```
q.filter('id' IN ids)??
```

or

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE :1 IN ids", id)
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  just `q.filter('ids', id)`.

Comment: How do you do it with GqlQuery?