# GAE Datastore query filter stringlist

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore, listproperty

In GAE models.py

```
class Article(db.Model):    
    tags = db.ListProperty(db.Category)
```

the article may have many tag(eg:'a', 'b','c'), so if i have a one(eg:'a') of tags of the article how do i to get the article record from datastore?

I know a way to fetch(), then compare but this way is too inefficient to really use it in life!

Comment: possible duplicate of [GAE GQL - get entity if list contains item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328412/gae-gql-get-entity-if-list-contains-item)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use equals. Like this:

```
tag = 'a'
articles = Article.gql('WHERE tags = :1', tag).fetch(100)
```

Comment: could you explain `':1'` for me, your code run right, but i can't understand why, In Google GQL [https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference"](Reference) I can't find out why!

Comment: :1 is a placeholder to represent each subsequent arg passed into the gql method. For example Article.gql('WHERE tags = :1 AND published = :2', tag, True) would use the variable 'tag' in place of :1 and True in place of :2

Comment: you may prefer to use filters instead - they are a bit easier to read. For example, Article.all().filter('tags', tag).fetch(100) is the same thing as Article.gql('WHERE tags = :1', tag).fetch(100)

Comment: does this make sense now?

Comment: `Article.gql("WHERE tags = :1", tag).fetch(100)` tag is a list, tags is a db.ListProperty(), `=` how to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
articles = Article.query().filter(Article.tags==tag).fetch(100)
```

And it seems that you are new to GAE , so i should advice you to switch to ndb instead of db as ndb is faster and handles caching itself.

Comment: this answer applies to ndb, but the question is written using db